# подскажите как изменить функцию?

Tags: javascript

Это изменение GET параметров в url

> Дело в том что при нажатии на `name` `ulr = index?sort=name`, а по
>   нажатию на `nums` `ulr = index?sort=nums`, но нужно чтобы результат был
>   таким `ulr = index?sort=name&sort=nums`

```
<a onclick="return setAttr('sort','name')">по name</a>
<a onclick="return setAttr('sort','nums')">по nums</a>
<script>
function setAttr(prmName,val){
    var res = '';
    var d = location.href.split("#")[0].split("?");
    var base = d[0];
    var query = d[1];
    if(query) {
        var params = query.split("&");
        for(var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            var keyval = params[i].split("=");
            if(keyval[0] != prmName) {
                res += params[i] + '&';
            }
        }
    }
    res += prmName + '=' + val;
    window.history.pushState(null, null, base + '?' + res);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: `if(keyval[0] !== prmName && keyval[1] !== val)`

Comment: @vp_arth  попробовал ваш вариант, все равно меняет а не добавляет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я в комментах ошибся немножко:

```
if(keyval[0] != prmName || keyval[1] != val) {
   res += params[i] + '&';
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/866m6192/)

---

Можно добавить проверку наличия текущего значения и убирать его:

```
if(keyval[0] == prmName && keyval[1] == val) {
   exists = true;
} else ...
```

А потом проверять и не добавлять этот параметр.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/866m6192/2/)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, все работает!!

Comment: только вот есть один вопрос, а можно реализовать удаление, допусти что нажатие производится на checkbox

Comment: может нужно при повторном нажатии проверить существует ли, если нет то убрать, подскажите как можно сделать, просто в `javascript` пока что не силен

Comment: нужно изучать.. Задача не такая простая, как кажется на первый взгляд. Лучше всего - корректно разбирать query в объект, модифицировать его и затем собирать заново...

Comment: @harbor, не пропустите обновление в ответе, скорее всего оно решает вашу задачу.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно попробовать:

```js
function setAttr(prmName, val) {
  var el = prmName + '=' + val;
  var res = '';
  var d = location.href.split("#")[0].split("?");
  var base = d[0];
  var query = d[1];

  if (query) {
    var params = query.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {      
      if (params.includes(el)) {
        console.log('Значение уже содержится');
        //console.log(location.href);
        return false;
      }else{
        res += params[i] + '&';
      }
    }
  }
  res += el;
  window.history.pushState(null, null, base + '?' + res);
  console.log(base + '?' + res);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="return setAttr('qsort','name')">qsort name</a>
<a onclick="return setAttr('sort','name')">sort name</a>
<a onclick="return setAttr('sort','nums')">sort nums</a>
```

В условии проверим наличие такого элемента с ключом и значением в массиве параметров `params`.

Comment: у вас определяет что значение уже содержится, можно удалить его допустим через `unset`?